# Having trouble with interface table structures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently working on a project that involves a third party database and application. So far we are able to successfully **TEST** and interface data between our databases. However we are having trouble when we are extracting a large set of data (ex 100000 rows and 10 columns per row) and suddenly it stopped at the middle of transaction for whatever reason(ex blackouts, force exit or etc..), missing or duplication of data is happening in this type of scenario.

Can you please give us a suggestions to handle these types of scenarios? Thank you!

Here's our current interface structure

```
OurDB -> Interface DB -> 3rdParty DB
```

**OurDB**: we are extracting records from `OurDB` (with bit column as false) to the `InterfaceDb`

**InterfaceDB**: after inserting records from `OurDB`, we will update OurDB bit column as true

**3rdPartyDB**: they will extract and delete all records from `InterfaceDB` (they assume that all records is for extraction)

Comment: What tools are you using to achieve this? Is it import/export feature of SQL or are you using any other ETL's? ETL tools such as SSIS offer better control of the data and do fast and better loading avoiding the blackouts/force exits. As to the way things are progressing, the current model of flagging the records and then deleting them is good. Am assuming you are likewise having a check to take only latest records.

Comment: hi @VKarthik sorry for the late reply. So far were only using sql and a c# application to do this. do you have any suggestions what other checking we needed to do before the extraction so that we can avoid duplicate data? i havent seen SSIS yet but ill research for it thank you for this suggestion btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you defintitely need a ETL tool then and preferably SSIS. First it will drastically improve your transfer rates while also providing robust error handling. Additionally you will have to use lookup transforms to ensure duplicates do not enter the sytsem. I would suggest go for Cache Connection Manager in order to perform the look-ups.

In terms of design, if your source system (OurDB) is having a primary key say recId, then have a column say source_rec_id in your InterfaceDB table. Say your first run has transferred 100 rows. Now in your second run, you would then need to pick 100+1th record and move on to the next rows. This way you will have a tracking mechanism and one-to-one correlation between source system and destination system to understand how many records have got transferred, how many are left etc.

For best understanding of SSIS go to [Channel 9 - msdn - SSIS](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=ssis#ch9Search&lang-en=en). Very helpful resource.

Comment: thanks! after discussing and brainstorming this with our team we concluded that this tool or app is the one we needed. i need a lot of researching though.. thanks again :)